# Как установить модуль php-xml на хостинг с доступом по ips manager?

Tags: php, linux, администрирование, хостинг, ispmanager

Есть сайт на `wordpress` куда нужно импортировать данные с помощью плагина [wpallimport](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/).
Однако получаю невозможность загрузки excel файла и ошибку:

> WP All Import requires DOMDocument, XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP
>   modules to be installed. These are standard features of PHP, and are
>   necessary for WP All Import to read the files you are trying to
>   import. Please contact your web hosting provider and ask them to
>   install and activate the DOMDocument, XMLReader, and XMLWriter PHP
>   modules.

Модули `XMLReader` и `XMLWriter` установлены, а вот для установки `DOMDocument` следует установить **php-xml** модуль

Пишу хостеру с просьбой его установить - получаю такой ответ:
"К сожалению у нас подобные вопросы выходят за рамки базового системного администрирования. Вам нужно сделать это самостоятельно или обратиться к Вашему системному администратору."

Как можно установить его самостоятельно? Хостинг с доступом по **ips manager** ?

Comment: Самое правильное будет - бежать с этого хостинга, с такими отписками. Без рутовых прав нельзя поставить какой-то модуль, если у хостера в панельке нет настроек, как например, на бегете, где можно менять конфигурацию php. Можно перенести сайт на нормальный хостинг с бесплатным тестовым периодом, импортировать что надо и перенести обратно

Comment: @Рашен Беар Стал детальнее разбираться - оказалось, что все же не просто хостинг, а выделенный сервер.

Нашел рекомендацию:
`sudo apt-get install php-xml

Затем вам нужно перезапустить apache, чтобы он вступил в силу.

sudo service apache2 restart`
А куда ее прописывать - подключиться через putty ?

Comment: Да, в консоль. Но лучше нанять специалиста.

Comment: 1) Указанная вами команда сработает далеко не на всех дистрибутивах.
2) `sudo service apache2 restart` - не делайте так =) `httpd -k restart`  - перезапуск apache2

Comment: @Владимир Клыков понял, спасибо - а в чем разница перезапуска? И еще нашел такую команду на перезапуск - она верная? `service httpd restart`

Comment: Разница в способе перезапуска, в случае ваших комманд - вы "убиваете" приложение и запускаете его повторно, в случае приведенной мной команды - вы говорите серверу "закончи свою работу, и перезапустись".. утрированно но факт =) можно сравнить(с натяжкой) с "пуск->перезагрузка" и кнопкой Reset на системном блоке =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков понял, буду знать, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнаружил, что для каждого из 4 проектов в ips manager были свои настройки и версии php на сервере, и соответственно для искомого сайта была выбрана нелогично, но другая версия, не в которой правил расширения.

Соответственно в ней и не был включен модуль  **XMLReader**

На решение натолкнула запись `php` версии в залоговке таблицы, которая отдает

```
phpinfo();
```

В панели не увидел где это написано